Do we use "rapport" for only transactional relationships (teacher/student; seller/buyer; doctor/patient...)?
I see this pattern in several dictionaries
build/ establish rapport between:
-teacher/student
-seller/buyer
-doctor/patient...
-coworker
Do we use "rapport" between friends? For example,
I built a close rapport with my friends in class.

Short answer: Yes.
thefreedictionary.com defines "rapport" as "Relationship, especially one of mutual trust or emotional affinity." That makes more sense for a relationship between two close friends or a boyfriend/girlfriend or husband/wife than between a seller and a buyer.
